# Linux: Total swap used = swap used by processes +?

Tags: linux, memory, swap

So, I'm trying to do some investigation on where does swap use come from in a system with high swap usage:

```
# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        515324     508800       6524          0       4852      27576
-/+ buffers/cache:     476372      38952
Swap:       983032     503328     479704
```

Adding up swap used per process:

```
# for proc in /proc/*; do cat $proc/smaps 2>/dev/null | awk '/Swap/{swap+=$2}END{print swap "\t'`readlink $proc/exe`'"}'; done | sort -n | awk '{total+=$1}/[0-9]/;END{print total "\tTotal"}'
0       /bin/gawk
0       /bin/sort
0       /usr/bin/readlink
28      /sbin/xxxxxxxx
52      /sbin/mingetty
52      /sbin/mingetty
52      /sbin/mingetty
52      /sbin/mingetty
56      /sbin/mingetty
56      /sbin/mingetty
60      /xxxxxxxxxxx
60      /usr/sbin/xxx
84      /usr/sbin/xxx
108     /usr/bin/xxx
168     /bin/bash
220     /sbin/init
256     /sbin/rsyslogd
352     /bin/bash
356     /bin/bash
360     /usr/sbin/sshd
496     /usr/sbin/crond
672     /usr/sbin/sshd
12972   /opt/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java
80392   /usr/libexec/mysqld
311876  /opt/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java
408780  Total
```

Which gives a lower value for total used swap. Where is the remaining used swapspace? Is it vmalloc()'ed memory inside the kernel? Something else? How can I identify it?

Output of meminfo:

```
# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       515324 kB
MemFree:          6696 kB
Buffers:          5084 kB
Cached:          28056 kB
SwapCached:     157512 kB
Active:         429372 kB
Inactive:        65068 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:       515324 kB
LowFree:          6696 kB
SwapTotal:      983032 kB
SwapFree:       478712 kB
Dirty:             100 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:      399456 kB
Mapped:           8792 kB
Slab:             7744 kB
PageTables:       1820 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:   1240692 kB
Committed_AS:  1743904 kB
VmallocTotal:   507896 kB
VmallocUsed:      3088 kB
VmallocChunk:   504288 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     4096 kB
```

Comment: Buffers and cache are included and they are not associated with any process.

Comment: @goldilocks: nope, those are in physical memory. Also, they don't add up.

Comment: You're right, I guess caching stuff to swap would be sort of pointless.  However, I think stuff that is swapped out may be left there and tracked even after the process which owns is defunct, as long as that swap space is not otherwise needed; this saves time later if a process loads the same page and then that page has to be swapped out again -- it's still there in swap already.  Google "swap cache" http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=314  This parallels how the actual "cache cache" comes to be (it's stuff saved in memory from now defunct processes).

Comment: ...meaning, lol, that "caching stuff *in* swap" is not so pointless, just that it doesn't get there by swapping the RAM cache out.

Comment: @goldilocks: that would be the SwapCached part in /proc/meminfo, which again, doesn't add up. It's also my understanding that SwapFree is updated whenever a swap page is gotten/released, regardless of whether it still exists as a swap_cache page.

Comment: See `mm/swapfile.c`: `free_swap_and_cache()` calls `swap_entry_free()` which increments `nr_swap_pages` (`SwapFree`), but only calls `delete_from_swap_cache()` (which decrements `total_swapcache_pages` - `SwapCached`) when the swap page is not still mapped elsewhere or the swap is full.

Comment: Look at this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system

Comment: Isn't the answer just that the kernel can swap, and that's not included in your processing?  Particularly the kernel has a whole heap of "user space" processes nowadays...  Just a considered guess tho.

Comment: AFAIK the SwapCached is pages that were in the swap and have been put back in memory most probably for reading, so once the read is done, the kernel can just reclaim the memory pages without touching the swap. I think Iain is probably right, the extra 100MB is kernel data swapped (e.g. modules which are currently not being actively used). However, I have no clue how to verify this.

Comment: it might be that you have a RAM-backed directory mounted somewhere.

Comment: Just a thought. Few processes have `task` directory containing few more running tasks. They also consume swap spaces. Try adding them too.  `e.g. /proc/12345/task/12346/smaps`

Comment: The issue you are observing isn't actually due to swap space being unaccounted for. The "(deleted)" that the kernel sometimes appends to /proc/*/exe links is output by `readlink` and is causing parse errors in your `awk` script, and you are effectively not counting processes whose binaries are no longer present in your total. The ongoing discussion about swap/caching/etc. going on here is a red herring. The more accurate question would have been "Why is my measurement of total swap usage different than what `free` reports?".

Comment: That's my question too - care to comment?: http://superuser.com/questions/603655/on-centos-6-3-why-do-several-swap-measuring-methods-return-different-results.

Answer (score 13):

The difference you are observing isn't actually due to swap space being unaccounted for. The "(deleted)" that the kernel sometimes appends to `/proc/*/exe` links is output by `readlink` and is causing parse errors in your awk script, and you are effectively not counting processes whose binaries are no longer present in your total.

Some kernels append the word "(deleted)" to `/proc/*/exe` symlink targets when the original executable for the process is no longer around.

The reason your command is showing less than the total is because of this. The output of `readlink` on such links will be something like "/path/to/bin (deleted)", which causes a parse error in `awk` when the output is substituted back into the string (it doesn't like the parentheses and spaces). For example, do this:

```
for a in /proc/*/exe ; do readlink $a ; done | grep deleted
```

And you will see a few entries with "(deleted)" appended. If you looked at the swap usage for these entries, their total would match the discrepancy you see, as the resulting `awk` errors prevent their totals from being calculated and included in the final total.

If you run your original command without redirecting stderr anywhere, you will probably notice a few "runaway string constant" errors. Those errors are a result of the above and you should not have ignored them.

Ignoring other potential improvements to your original command, you could modify it by removing the " (deleted)", like this (note `|awk '{print $1}'` added to `readlink` output):

```
for proc in /proc/*; \
  do cat $proc/smaps 2>/dev/null | awk '/Swap/{swap+=$2}END{print swap "\t'`readlink $proc/exe|awk '{print $1}' `'" }'; \
done | sort -n | awk '{total+=$1}/[0-9]/;END{print total "\tTotal"}'
```

This use of `awk` to fix the output of `readlink` may break if the name contains spaces -- you can use `sed` or whatever method you prefer.

**Bonus Info**

By the way, you could just use `smem -t`. The "Swap" column displays what you want.

As for calculating it yourself, though, you can also get this information more directly from the `VmSwap` field in `/proc/*/status` (smaps requires some kernel support and isn't always available), and avoid having to redirect error output by using a proper filename pattern that avoids the errors to begin with:

```
for proc in /proc/[0-9]*; do \
  awk '/VmSwap/ { print $2 "\t'`readlink $proc/exe | awk '{ print $1 }'`'" }' $proc/status; \
done | sort -n | awk '{ total += $1 ; print $0 } END { print total "\tTotal" }'
```

If you don't need the actual binary and can deal with just having the process name, you can get *everything* from `status`:

```
for a in /proc/*/status ; do \
  awk '/VmSwap|Name/ { printf $2 " " } END { print "" }' $a ; \
done | awk '{ total+=$2 ; print $0 } END { print "Total " total }'
```

And finally, if just having the PIDs suffices, you can just do it all with `awk`:

```
awk '/VmSwap/ { total += $2; print $2 "\t" FILENAME } END { print total "\tTotal" }' /proc/*/status
```

**Note:**

Now this isn't to say that there aren't differences between `free` and `smem` (the latter being the same as your script). There are plenty (see, for example, https://www.google.com/search?q=smem+free, which has more than enough results on the first page to answer your questions about memory usage). But without a proper test, your specific situation cannot be addressed.

Comment: The `smem -t` incorrectly computes swap usage, too. For example, if you run Apache with lots of childs for a long time the `smem -t` may report each child using e.g. 40 MB of swap and the total swap reported exceeds the available swap space. In reality, Apache has swapped ~40 MB and every forked child is reported to use the same swap area. Basically the problem is similar to Rss vs Pss data in `/proc/*/smaps`.

Answer (score 7):

Swap is also used by the tmpfs if the kernel needs more free ram or simply because it's unused for some time... so any tmpfs usage might consume swap.

Comment: Why the downvote ? This is absolutely correct.