# Why does /proc/*/status not account for all swap used on a system?

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I have a system that has been swapping recently and am unable to account for all swap that is shown as in use by tools like `free` or `top`.

Specifically, I can account for 19GB of 28GB swap used (according to free) by summing the VmSwap values as reported by `/proc/*/status`.

Does anyone know what the remaining 9GB of swap could be used by and if there is a way I can find what is using it?

(I found [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71714/linux-total-swap-used-swap-used-by-processes) but it seemed to suggest that `/proc/*/status` would account for all swap)

Thanks

Comment: File systems using `tmpfs` use swap when their files are forced out of memory.

Comment: I see. There is a tmpfs mount on this system but it only seems to be using 18MB (at least according to df).